# How to save log message to file (labstack/echo)

Tags: go, logging, go-echo

I need help..

I am using golang, and currently I want to save my log into logger file. I used echo framework for logging, like this:

```
e.Use(middleware.LoggerWithConfig(middleware.LoggerConfig{
  Format: "method=${method}, uri=${uri}, status=${status}\n",
}))
```

Does anyone knows How to save it into file?

Comment: `LoggerConfig` has an `Output` field which defaults to `os.Stdout`. You can put any reader there, including the one returned by `os.Openfile`/`os.Create`. You can also modify `DefaultLoggerConfig` to apply the change to all logger instances.

Answer (score 1):

`Output` field of `LoggerConfig` is [io.Writer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer). Set to `Output` field any [io.Writer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) implementation

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("logfile", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("error opening file: %v", err))
}
defer f.Close()

// Middleware
e.Use(middleware.LoggerWithConfig(middleware.LoggerConfig{
    Format: "method=${method}, uri=${uri}, status=${status}\n",
    Output: f,
}))
```